# Why does rspec falsely pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am working on a project to learn how to use rspec with ruby on rails.

So I wrote a spec to test if my app emails new comments when a user has given permission to receive emails and doesn't email if the user has not given permission.

```
###COMMENT SPEC###
require 'rails_helper'
describe Comment do

  include TestFactories

  describe "after_create" do

    before do
      @post = associated_post
      @user = authenticated_user
      @comment = Comment.new(body: 'My comment', post: @post, user_id: 1000)
    end

    context "with user's permission" do

      it "sends an email to users who have favorited the post" do
        @user.favorites.where(post: @post).create 

        allow( FavoriteMailer )
          .to receive(:new_comment)
          .with(@user, @post, @comment)
          .and_return( double(deliver: true) )

        @comment.save  ### Test fails if this changes to @comment.save!
      end

      it "does not send emails to users who haven't" do
        expect( FavoriteMailer )
          .not_to receive(:new_comment)

        @comment.save  ### Test fails if this changes to @comment.save!
      end
    end

    context "without permission" do

      before { @user.update_attribute(:email_favorites, false) }

      it "does not send emails, even to users who have favorited" do
        @user.favorites.where(post: @post).create

        expect( FavoriteMailer )
          .not_to receive(:new_comment)

        @comment.save  ### Test fails if this changes to @comment.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my test factory

```
module TestFactories

  def associated_post(options={})
    post_options = {
      title: 'Post title',
      body: 'Post bodies must be pretty long.',
      topic: Topic.create(name: 'Topic name'),
      user: authenticated_user
    }.merge(options)

    Post.create(post_options)
  end

  def authenticated_user(options={})
    user_options = {email: "email#{rand}@fake.com", password: 'password'}.merge(options)
    user = User.new(user_options)
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.save
    user
  end
end
```

Now if I change @comment.save to @comment.save! for a test in the spec, the test fails and I get the following error:

```
Comment after_create without permission does not send emails, even to users who have favorited
Failure/Error: @comment.save!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
Validation failed: User can't be blank
```

Is my factory flawed or is this test flawed?
I'm getting confused about what's really wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: `user_id: 1000` - there's no such user. And you have presence validation on it.

Comment: Ah so by using comment.save!, I'm deliberately breaking the test because I can't save a comment tied to a user that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes. The `!` raises an error if the comment fails to save (because of a validation). Without the `!`, `@comment.save` just returns false, and the comment fails to save silently.